# Is there a consistent way to use associative arrays in Cake Session Component methods?

Tags: cakephp

I ask because the inability to use associative arrays which contain decimal or integer values means I cannot store the shoe size in the session. e.g. the following does not work:

```
$shoe_id = 'Shoe_1';
$size = '38.5';
$qu = 1;

$this->Session->write(array('order_array','items',$shoe_id,$size,'quantity'), $qu);
```

and I have to use

```
$_SESSION['order_array']['items'][$shoe_id][$size]['quantity'] = $qu;
```

instead. Is there a common way of using associative arrays in all of the Session Component methods?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need a string on first parameter and value in second parameter. But your string can represent an array of CakePHP, for example:

```
$this->Session->write('Country.state.city', 'Anyone');
```

And read:

```
echo $this->Session->read('Country.state.city');
```

This represent this array:

```
Array
(
    [Country] => Array
        (
            [state] => Array
                (
                    [city] => Anyone
                )

        )

)
```

Is your question about it?

Comment: Please read the question before answering. In the example I posted the resulting string would be:  $this->Session->write->'order_array.items.Shoe_1.38.5.quantity', $qu); notice the '38.5' just got split up by the dot...

Comment: I read and I explained that its your implementation is wrong. Check the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html?highlight=write). There's no way, not just in CakePHP but the PHP does not allow decimal in index on array, check manual too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess the answer to my question is 'No, there is no consistent way to use associative arrays in CakePHP Session Component methods'

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the way you store the data.

```
Array(
  [order_array] => Array(
    [items] => Array(
      0 => Array(
        name => Shoe_1,
        size => 38.5,
        quantity => 1,
      )
    )
  )
)
```

It would fix your issue de facto.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to convert the decimal sizes to whole numbers (multiply by 10). These could then be stored thus:

```
$this->Session->write('order_array.items.'.$shoe_id.'.'.$size.'.quantity', 1);
```

Many thanks for your replies!